# How to remove red from antd upload

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

I am using the Upload component antd.For any reason it shows the upload file in red even though when submit image successfully change. I try returning false from beforeUpload but if I do this while using antd-img-crop, the cropping functionality does not work.How to remove color red when upload the file while keep ant-img-crop function?

[image]

```
 const [newPicture, setNewPicture] = useState<any[]>([]);

  const handleImageUpload = async (info: any) => {
    let fileList = [...info.fileList];
    fileList = fileList.slice(-1);

    fileList = fileList.map((file) => {
      if (file.response) {
        file.url = file.response.url;
      }
      return file;
    });

    setNewPicture(fileList);
  };

  const onPreview = async (file: UploadFile) => {
    let src = file.url as string;
    if (!src) {
      src = await new Promise((resolve) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(file.originFileObj as RcFile);
        reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result as string);
      });
    }
    const image = new (Image as any)();
    image.src = src;
    const imgWindow = window.open(src);
    imgWindow?.document.write(image.outerHTML);
  };


  console.log(newPicture);
  const toast = useToast();

  const navigate = useNavigate();


  const handleSubmit = async () => {
    const formData = new FormData();

    if (newPicture) {
      formData.append('profilePhoto', newPicture[0]?.originFileObj || newPicture[0]?.url);
    }
    formData.append('subscribeNewsletter', String(isSubscribe));

    try {
      await fetchFormData({
        method: 'PATCH',
        path: 'member/data',
        data: formData,
      }).then((response) => {
        if (!response.error) {
          toast({
            title: 'Berhasil',
            description: 'Profil Anda telah berhasil diperbaharui',
            status: 'success',
            duration: 9000,
            isClosable: true,
          });
          getMemberData();
        } else {
          toast({
            title: 'Error',
            description: response.message,
            status: 'error',
            duration: 9000,
            isClosable: true,
          });
        }
      });
    } catch (error) {
      toast({
        title: 'Error',
        description: error.message,
        status: 'error',
        duration: 9000,
        isClosable: true,
      });
    }
  };


  return (          

<ImgCrop cropShape="round">
      <Upload
        action="https://run.mocky.io/v3/435e224c-44fb-4773-9faf-380c5e6a2188"
        name="Profile Picture"
        listType="picture-circle"
        fileList={newPicture}
        onChange={handleImageUpload}
        onPreview={onPreview}
        // beforeUpload={()=> false}
        showUploadList={{
          showPreviewIcon:false
        }}
       
      >
        {newPicture.length < 1 && '+ Edit'}
      </Upload>
      
    </ImgCrop>
```

Comment: It's better to have full code or any codesandbox instance. So that, you can get better help.

Answer (score 0):

One way to remove or update the antd upload default border is to override the default CSS.

```
.ant-upload {
  border: none;
}
```

Comment: i try that but still not working

Comment: Can you please provide a codesandbox or codepan instance? Or full related code. So that I can run the application on my side?

Comment: i follow exactly like this example https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/crop-image-before-uploading-antd-5-11-5-87gf6g